# Style file and iOS TexPad app

Tags: packages, texpad

I am trying to typeset my project using TeXpad app on my iPhone 11 (iOS 13.6) and I wish to use my own style. I tried to put my style file `mypaper.sty` into linked iCloud folder, and into local iPhone folder, and in the special directory Texpad-Custom-Packages directory. In any case, it says

```
LaTeX Error: File 'mypaper.sty' not found
```

Here is the minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp866]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs,amscd,comment}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs,amscd}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[hyper]{mypaper}

\begin{document}

\title{My title}

\author[Me]{Me}
\address{My adress}
\email{My email}
\date{21.06.2020}
\maketitle
\markright{Title}
\begin{fulltext}
\begin{abstract}
My abstract
\underbar{\today}
\end{abstract}
\begin{keywords}
My KW
\end{keywords}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}\tableofcontents
\footnotetext[0]{My foot}
\section{Section name}\label{s1}
\subsection{}\label{s1s1}
\end{fulltext}
\end{document}
```

I tried to change the way to my file in `\usepackage[hyper]{mypaper}`, but also no results.

Comment: I don't use Texpad, but the related official help page may help: [How do I add custom packages to TexpadTeX](https://www.texpad.com/support/tex/texpadtex/texpadtex-custom-packages).

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: Perhaps you can contact the Texpad team for help.

Comment: Yea, I will try to do so.